# A Django EAV attempt

Tags: python, django

This seems to do the job of the EAV tables. Besides being EAV, is there room for improvement? Maybe there is something obvious, but how about indexing certain columns?

```
from django.db import models


class Entity(models.Model):
    entity_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    entity = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Attribute(models.Model):
    attribute_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    entity_id = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class EntityTableAbstract(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    entity_id = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    attribute_id = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)


class EntityVarchar(EntityTableAbstract):
    value = models.TextField()


class EntityInteger(EntityTableAbstract):
    value = models.IntegerField()
```